# Проблема с созданием входа на сайте

Tags: php

создала страницу блога с регистрацией и входом подключила базу, регистрация работает, а вот вход пишет, что такого пользователя нет. Не знаю что делать подскажите пожалуйста.

```
<?php
    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $password = md5($password."qidhoqwhi701089");

    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','','registration_blog');

    $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` ='$password'");

    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if(count($user) == 0) {
        echo "Такой пользователь не найден";
    exit();
    }

prin_r($user);
exit();

    $mysql->close();

    header('Location: /');

?>
```

при вводе в поле логина и пароля этого пользователя [image: phpmyadmin]

выдает, что такого пользователя нет

Comment: Ну выведите информацию по логину паролю и сверьте с данными в БД. Там либо пусто, либо данные разные.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ну как может там быть пусто, если я вижу в базе 
admin и пароль 123456(в MD5). И он и так должен вывести данные у меня ведь написано
prin_r($user);
exit();
а так просто не видит почему-то пользователей....

Comment: проблема в том, что css код не видит пользователей в базе

Comment: @АлисаЗайка Во первых.. CSS код ? Причем тут стили и база данных ? Уберите md5 и возьмите нормальный password_hash. Во вторых, не `prin_r`, а `print_r`.

Comment: Ой  php, простите.  Значит не работает из-за  md5?  Cпасибо не заметила Prin.

Comment: @АлисаЗайка нет, не из за md5.  зайдите на оф. документацию, там есть пояснения, почему не надо использовать md5 для хранения паролей и почему нужно использовать password_hash.

Comment: волшебный логин для входа `' OR 1=1 #`